# Is it possible to execute a function on a user object in Twig?

Tags: 8, theming, users

You can use hook_entity_load to add fields to the user object like so:

```
function mymodule_entity_load($entities, $type)
{
    if ($type == 'user'  )
    {
       foreach($entities as $e) {
         $e->myField = 'hello';
       }
    }
}
```

That will allow me to do this in twig:

```
{{ user.myField }}
```

This is quite useful, but it would be  great if I could do this:

```
{{ user.getActivity() }}
```

Or more specifically:

```
<h1>Members</h1>
<ul>
    {% for activity in user.getActivity()  %}
        <li>{{ activity.time }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Is there a way to add a "function" in this way?

Comment: Yes, twig can call object methods. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15277822/8507497

Comment: Where is that activity info coming from? Why don't you simply add a normal field to the user entity? Why do you need it exactly that way in Twig? Wouldn't it be easier to simply hook_preprocess the user and add the info from there if you only need it in Twig?

Comment: But no, you can't add methods to an object/class at runtime